# Trying to pull stock data from Yahoo Finance using Python 3.5

Tags: python

Hello I have this code but am getting these errors

**main loop 'tuple' object has no attribute 'read'** AND
**main loop module 'urllib' has no attribute 'urlopen'**

```
def pullData(stock):
    try:
        fileLine = stock+'.txt'
        urlToVisit = 'http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/'+stock+'/chartdata;type=quote;range=10d/csv'
        sourceCode = urllib.urlopen(urlToVisit).read()
        splitSource = sourceCode.split('\n')

        for eachLine in splitSource:
            splitLine = eachLine.split(',')
            if len(splitLine)==6:
                if 'values' not in eachLine:
                    saveFile = open(fileLine,'a')
                    lineToWrite = eachLine+'\n'
                    saveFile.write(lineToWrite)

        print('Pulled',stock)
        print('sleeping')
        time.sleep(5)

    except Exception as e:
        print('main loop',str(e))

pullData(stockToPull)
```

Comment: How are you getting two errors? Is mhawke's answer not helping?

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, `urlopen()` is in [`urllib.request`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen), so you can do this:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

sourceCode = urlopen(urlToVisit).read()
```

Regarding the rest of your code you might be better off using a HTML parser such as [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or [lxml.html](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html).

Comment: Thanks. solves that. However, now I get this message when running the last line of code:                                                                          pullData(stockToPull)
main loop a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: `urllib.urlopen(urlToVisit).read()` returns a `bytes` object. You then attempt to split the bytes object with a `str` object, which can't be done. You need to either decode the bytes object before splitting with `splitSource = sourceCode.decode('ascii').split('\n')`, or you can just iterate over the response object returned by `urlopen()` remembering to decode each line before processing further.